# Why are there many internet grammar lesson examples using past perfect with "before" but not with "after"?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect

I know that I have to use past perfect when using before.

> I had eaten before I swam.

But why don't I need to use past perfect with after?

> I swam after I ate.

Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: Where are you wondering about the past perfect in the second sentence, with swimming or with eating?

Comment: Related questions, [Past perfect and using before/after](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217384/past-perfect-and-using-before-after) and [Past Perfect sentences with “before”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90314/past-perfect-sentences-with-before) and [Past Perfect question forms with 'before' etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112565/past-perfect-question-forms-with-before-etc).

Comment: Question is based on a false premise. "I ate before I swam" is not wrong, either grammatically or logically.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use past perfect with *before*.  In fact, *before* takes the place of past perfect.

***I ate before I swam***.  Perfectly fine sentence that conveys the meaning.  The order of events is eating followed by swimming.

On the other hand, using *after* is confusing because PP is about the order of things before something in the past, not after.

***I had eaten after I swam*** is just plain strange and confusing.

***I swam after I had eaten*** is acceptable because swimming happens after eating and swimming is listed first.  You could also say ***After I had eaten, I swam.*** I would say,  ***After I had eaten, I went swimming.***

Comment: What about **I swam after I had eaten** and **I swam after I ate**? are they both correct?

Comment: I'm adding that right now.

Comment: This is not a suitable question for ELU.